# Azure devops migration tools cant find required field

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to migrate an Azure DevOps project from one organization to another organization. I get the following message at console output.

> [08:22:35 INF] Found target project as myTestProject [08:22:35 WRN]
> ValidatingRequiredField: Epic does not contain
> Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId

Do this mean that the custom process used has to be used in target project?
If so, is there a method to export processes in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

The message actually only means that the Epic work item is missing the ReflectedWorkItemId field (see [documentation](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/server-configuration.html#:%7E:text=Inherited%20Templates%20%2D%20the%20future) and [documentation 2](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/server-configuration.html#:%7E:text=Inherited%20Templates%20%2D%20the%20future:%7E:text=Editing%20the%20configuration)).

The field is used to store the state of the migration. Each affected WI Type (Source + Target) must have this field. Depending on the Process Model type you use the old tooling (witadmin) or the new tooling(web access).

"Custom" actually only means a derived process template. With the inheritance model you cannot change the template directly, but derive from the Microsoft original.

Comment: Thank yuo for the answer. The problem is the field Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId are in the source epic, but not in the epic for target. 
Do the source and target process need to match?
If they need to match, are there any way to export the source process?

Comment: The fields do not have to match. You can use different fields for source and destination. I have provided a second link in my answer, there you can see it well in the example.